# EF Core - Set DbSet<T> for remote DBContext

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Using EF Core - Dotnet 6 I'm trying to develop a class library for API.

Database **MySQL**

```cs
public partial class AvengerContext: DbContext
{

    public AvengerContext(DbContextOptions<AvengerContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(AvengerContext).Assembly);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Above code resides in AvengerContext.dll, now I want to write the Entities & Entity configuration and attachend to AvengerContext
Could I get way to achieve it.

Comment: *now I want to write the Entities & Entity configuration* -- Well, go ahead. Please come back if you have a more pointed question. You're asking to write an entire data layer here.

Comment: Im not looking at entire data layer here, Im looking at how to can I implement
1. I have dbcontext is a DLL
2. How can I extend my code so that my dll Entity & Entity configuration can be attached to that remote dbcontext